# Update query using Max in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I'm new to MS access, I have a question.
I have 2 tables let say A and B.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like an sql query which updates the table Table A from Table B, based on ID and Max(Order Rank)..the result shows in the Resultant table i.e. Table A. 
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Vijay Krishnan

Comment: you want `MAX(Order Rank)` or `MAX(Price)`, cause in picture I see one thing and in text other?

Comment: For each ID in TABLE A, i would like to see the corresponding Price from Table B by Max(Order Rank)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
SET a.Price = b.Price
WHERE b.OrderRank=(SELECT MAX(OrderRank) FROM TableB WHERE ID=b.ID);
```